# API Call Consumption for Synchronized Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

As I couldn't find much documentation concerning details of sync process between sales/service cloud and marketing cloud I was wondering whether somebody can help me with the following questions:

1.Obviously, the size of the synchronised objects play part in the number of API calls needed but I would like to understand whether the process only attempts to sync information which has been updated since the previous sync took place or rather brings in all the information from sales cloud to marketing cloud regardless whether they have changed or not?

2.Additionally, what is the bulk size? If for example, I am syncing 1 object with 10 fields in it and each field contains 10 records (overall 100 separate data points). How will many API calls be required to sync such object?

Answer (score 2):

API calls for Marketing Cloud synchronization aren't counted for your API-call limit (just like API-Calls for reports in Sales/Service Cloud, they are only shown in the call reports, but don't decrease your available calls per 24h).

If you like you can check the used calls in Sales/Service cloud using the report *API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days* that is available in the *Administrative Reports* folder. In this report identifying Marketing Cloud API-calls is very easy as they contain "ExactTarget" in the *Client Id* column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From what I have read around, REST and SOAP API calls are not counted towards the limit indeed but BULK API. The reason why I am digging into it is that a couple days ago we have actually maxed out our daily limit. Trying to bring the level down I have paused the synchronisation on some salesforce objects and this really pushed the numbers down. Could be possible that the object sync is using bulk API?

Comment: Just to be sure: You ran into your Sales/Service Cloud API-Limit? If so, did you reach the maximum number of bulk jobs or API calls? Did you check the administrative report I referenced in my answer to check where the API-calls came from? If so, were the API-calls NOT coming from Marketing Cloud enough to reach your limit? Are there any other suspicious activities?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the report and it looks that we really hit the limit for our API calls. In that report, I could see that the large share of the calls was marked as Exact Target.  The reason why we even discovered that we have a problem is that we started syncing Task object between SF and MC which is a big data set. Once this sync started we began receiving errors when trying to sync our own database with SF. The error message was warning us that we reached the API limits.  From what the SF support told me this shouldn't have happened and they are looking into this right now.

Comment: Thats what I guessed as like mentioned in my post I've been told that API-calls made from Marketing Cloud (Connect) don't count for the API limit...

Answer (score 2):

@Piotr Caputa: did you update the Connected App? Per this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233192&language=en_US&type=1), it recommends you update your installed managed package and the connected app in order to lift the API limits. Based on this documentation, it says the "ConnectedApp Authentication will lift the limits of the SOAP API and Replication API used by MC Connect and Data Stream" and that the "ConnectedApp Authentication does not lift limits of the BulkAPI, which is utilized by MC Connect for any Tracking Data."

The SOAP & Replication APIs are what's used in synchronized data extensions. BulkAPI isn't. BulkAPI are calls that can be used programatically.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the connector to the latest version but this didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: My next suggestion was going to recommend you submit a MC Support ticket, but it looks like you already did. Please post an update with a resolution. I'm interested to see how the data stream is processing those records that they would count against your limit.

Comment: There is still a lot of back and forward between me and the support team but once I know the final answer, I will post it here.

Comment: @PiotrCaputa what was the issue?